# Images inside of flexbox not all even

Tags: css, flexbox

http://kijpi.ddns.net/news-homepage-main/

I can't figure out why the images (all 200x254) at the bottom 3 columns of the page are distorted inside of their flexbox. All 3 images are sized differently and I don't understand why.

if someone can look at this code and sees a problem that could cause this please let me know.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-display: swap;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  src: url(assets/fonts/Inter-VariableFont_slnt_wght.ttf) format('truetype');
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  margin: 80px auto;
  background-color: #fefdf9;
  width: 1110px;
  display: grid;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box-left {
  flex-basis: 728px;
}

.box-right {
  flex-basis: 350px;
}

.img-container {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.img-container .mobile-img-main {
  display: none;
}

.mini-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.mini-row__col1 {
  flex-basis: 48%;
}

.mini-row__col2 {
  flex-basis: 48%;
}

.top-articles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.top-articles__col {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.top-img-container {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <title>Frontend Mentor | News homepage</title>

    <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
    <style>
      .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
      .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header class="header">
      <img src="assets/images/logo.svg">
      <nav>
        <svg width="32" height="31" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="#00001A" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="m2.919.297 28.284 28.284-2.122 2.122L.797 2.419z"/><path d="M.797 28.581 29.081.297l2.122 2.122L2.919 30.703z"/></g></svg>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>New</li>
          <li>Popular</li>
          <li>Trending</li>
          <li>Categories</li>
        </ul>
        <svg width="40" height="17" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="#00001A" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M0 0h40v3H0zM0 7h40v3H0zM0 14h40v3H0z"/><path d="M0 0h40v3H0z"/></g></svg>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
      
      <div class="box-left">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img class="desktop-img-main" src="assets/images/image-web-3-desktop.jpg" alt="">
          <img class="mobile-img-main" src="assets/images/image-web-3-mobile.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="mini-row">
          <div class="mini-row__col1">
            <h1>The Bright Future of Web 3.0?</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="mini-row__col2">
            <p>We dive into the next evolution of the web that claims to put the power of the platforms back into the hands of the people. 
              But is it really fulfilling its promise?</p>
              <button class="btn">READ MORE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box-right">
        <h2>New</h2>
        <h4 class="article-heading">Hydrogen VS Electric Cars</h4>
        <p class="article-text">Will hydrogen-fueled cars ever catch up to EVs?</p>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <h4 class="article-heading">The Downsides of AI Artistry</h4>
        <p class="article-text">What are the possible adverse effects of on-demand AI image generation?</p>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <h4 class="article-heading">Is VC Funding Drying Up?</h4>
        <p class="article-text">Private funding by VC firms is down 50% YOY. We take a look at what that means.</p>
      </div>

    </main>

    <section class="top-articles">
      <div class="top-articles__col">
        <div class="top-img-container">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/twG2f.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="top-articles-text">
          <h3 class="top-num">01</h3>
          <p class="top-heading">Reviving Retro PCs</p>
          <p class="top-blurb">What happens when old PCs are given modern upgrades?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="top-articles__col">
        <div class="top-img-container">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCf3q.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="top-articles-text">
          <h3 class="top-num">02</h3>
          <p class="top-heading">Top 10 Laptops of 2022</p>
          <p class="top-blurb">Our best picks for various needs and budgets.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="top-articles__col">
        <div class="top-img-container">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6m1d.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="top-articles-text">
          <h3 class="top-num">03</h3>
          <p class="top-heading">The Growth of Gaming</p>
          <p class="top-blurb">How the pandemic has sparked fresh opportunities.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
      Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried specifying a specific width, I've tried changing the size of the container, I've tried removing the margin-right from the top-img-container and nothing has worked. I was expecting 3 exact columns of 30% with the images being equally sized in each one.

Comment: In the [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/82548) I've created for you, from your code (and, next time, please do this yourself) could you add links to the pictures or placeholder images in order that we can see the varying sizes, instead of the broken-image icon?

Comment: Adding an external image link doesn't work when I tried. How can I do it? I did include a link at the top of the post to the live site which shows the images

Comment: Add the links in a comment, and I - or another - can edit them into the question on your behalf. It may be due to your relatively low reputation.

Comment: #1 
http://kijpi.ddns.net/news-homepage-main/assets/images/image-retro-pcs.jpg 
#2 
http://kijpi.ddns.net/news-homepage-main/assets/images/image-top-laptops.jpg 
#3
http://kijpi.ddns.net/news-homepage-main/assets/images/image-gaming-growth.jpg

Comment: Thanks, I've added those to the question and - looking at the snippet - this doesn't seem to reproduce your problem, at least on Firefox 119/Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I included the entire code now and it should reproduce

Comment: Regardless of the final solution, I would expect to see `object-fit` used on those image's.

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the resolution. Post what you did as an **answer**

Answer (score 0):

Removing the

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

fixed the issue. I don't understand why it broke it though.